# flex items do not overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My CSS experiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>Two</div>
      <div>Three</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px dotted lightcoral;
  display: flex;
}

.box div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

here the width of the flex items is more than the flex container size but still the items do not overflow on the main axis. When I inspect the element I notice that the width of the flex items is 100px, but i have given them a width of 200px. So why is browser not giving the flex items a width of 200px?

The link I am following is : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 4):

If you add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the flex items to prevent their automatic shrinking, they keep their defined width , causing an overflow.

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px dotted lightcoral;
  display: flex;
}

.box div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the tutorial you linked:

> The live sample below contains items that have been given a width, the
>   total width of the items being too wide for the flex container. As
>   flex-wrap is set to wrap, the items wrap. Set it to nowrap, which is
>   also the initial value, and they will instead shrink to fit the
>   container because they are using initial flexbox values that allows
>   items to shrink.

Comment: okay i understand there are some initial values set..later in the article it says flex-shrink defaults to 1. may be that is the reason.

Comment: @tin_tin Yup, you haven't set the `flex-wrap` attribute so it's defaulting to `nowrap`, which is causing it to ignore your `width` values. Note, if you set the `width` to a value small enough to fit inside the outer div, they would not stretch beyond that value. BTW, if this answers your question, please hit the check mark for me.